# pq: bind message supplies 1 parameters, but prepared statement "" requires 0

Tags: database, postgresql, go

I am trying to run a postgres if statement at my golang project, but i met this error, could you help me figure out?

the code is

```
newDate := "2022-06-22"
query := `
    DO $$
    DECLARE
    new_date date:= $1;
    BEGIN
    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM systemtable WHERE date = new_date) THEN
    UPDATE systemtable SET is_latest = TRUE WHERE date = new_date;
    ELSE
    INSERT INTO systemtable (date, is_latest) VALUES (new_date, TRUE);
    END IF;
    END$$;`

if _, err := txi.Exec(query, newDate); err != nil {
    return err 
}
```

Then the error returned is `"pq: bind message supplies 1 parameters, but prepared statement "" requires 0"`

Comment: DO command can not do with argument. Can you try function.

Comment: do u mean if i have to use external parameter i cannot use postgres if statement?

Comment: `DO` executes an *anonymous code block*. The code block is treated as though it were the body of a function **with no parameters**. *It is parsed and executed a single time.* The code block MUST be specified as a **string literal** (`$$ ... $$` *is* a dollar-quoted string literal). You CANNOT use parameter placeholders inside string literals. A `$1` inside a string literal is NOT a parameter placeholder, it is just a dollar sign followed by a one, it has no special meaning, it is interpreted literally.

Comment: @DietPepsi note that for what you're trying to do there is not need to actually use `DO`. PostgreSQL has had support, for quite some while now, for "upserts". See the `ON CONFLICT` clause [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/sql-insert.html#SQL-ON-CONFLICT).

Answer (score 0):

Do your job with two separate statements within a transaction. That way you preserve consistency and don't have to perform any business logic on database side.